# Is there any way to choose if a default parameter is used for a function?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, parameters, default

For example:

```
def tune(a=2,b=3,c=4):
    return str(a) + " " + str(b) + " " + str(c) 

print tune(5, *default*, 7)
```

so that the output would be:

```
5 3 7
```

What do I put in place of the `*default*` to make this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use default named arguments. Explicitly mention that `c` has to take the value of `7`

```
>>> print tune(5, c= 7) 
5 3 7
```

Comment: In other words: simply do *not* pass a value for `b`.

Comment: Glad to be of help @cadams. All the best